# Grails 5.2 can't deploy to JBoss EAP 7.4

Tags: grails, jboss, jboss-eap-7, grails-5

Grails 5.2

1. create-app helloworld
2. create-controller hello (add render "Hello"
   line)
3. Add the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file to WEB-INF folder for JBoss logging compatibility.
4. run-app (works)
5. war
6. Deploy to JBoss EAP 7.4 and get following error

```
    ERROR [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) Application run failed: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [io.micronaut.context.event.ApplicationEventPublisher<io.micronaut.context.event.StartupEvent>] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2778)
```

I did set the logging level to TRACE for is.micronaut.context.condition but nothing is logged at the TRACE level.

The JBoss jboss-deployment-structure.xml file that I added, which I think is standard for JBoss EAP, looks like this. I do not believe this is related, I'm just including it here so that others can reproduce what I did to generate the war file.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
    <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies     -->
    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.slf4j" />
        <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
    </exclusions>
</deployment>
```

How can I make a grails 5 app deployable to JBoss EAP 7.4?